# Flutter - The method 'changeLanguage' was called on null

Tags: flutter, localization

I am new to Flutter and I want to do in-app localization. I tried to follow steps from [HERE](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2) and manage to do localization based on phone's locale.

However, when I tried to do in-app localization, I got this error:

```
The method 'changeLanguage' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: changeLanguage(Instance of 'Locale')
```

Below is my code part where I call the changeLanguage:

```
void _showLanguageBottomSheet() {
AppLanguage appLanguage = Provider.of<AppLanguage>(context);
showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: false,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    context: context,
    builder: (builder) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 20, 15, 15),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Palette.white,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: const Radius.circular(15),
              topRight: const Radius.circular(15),
            )),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            // Title
            Text(
                "${AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('change_language')}",
                style: CustomTextStyle.blackLargeBoldText),

            SizedBox(height: 10),

            // Buttons
            Row(children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: englishLabel(),
                onTap: () {
                  englishSelected = true;
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  appLanguage.changeLanguage(Locale("en"));
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 15),
              GestureDetector(
                  child: chineseLabel(),
                  onTap: () {
                    englishSelected = false;
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    appLanguage.changeLanguage(Locale("zh"));
                  })
            ])
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
 }
```

And below is the changeLanguage function in AppLanguage class. I follow exactly from the tutorial in this [link](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-internationalization-the-easy-way-using-provider-and-json-c47caa4212b2):

```
void changeLanguage(Locale type) async {
var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if (_appLocale == type) {
  return;
}
if (type == Locale("zh")) {
  _appLocale = Locale("zh");
  await prefs.setString('language_code', 'zh');
  await prefs.setString('countryCode', 'Hans');
} else {
  _appLocale = Locale("en");
  await prefs.setString('language_code', 'en');
  await prefs.setString('countryCode', 'UK');
}
notifyListeners();
}
```

When I tried to debug, the code did not even get through the changeLanguage function. Error was thrown at the **appLanguage.changeLanguage(Locale("zh"));** or **appLanguage.changeLanguage(Locale("en"));** line. I'm not sure why it is null. I hope someone can help me with this :(